# Fazer desaparecer botões com base em login

Tags: objective-c, button, display

Eu estou com o problem na alteração dos botões da toolbar (BarButton Items) consoante o utilizador está login ou não.

TableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   User *userObj = [[User alloc] init];

   if([userObj userAuthenticated]){

     [self showLoginButtons];
   }
   else{

     [self showLogoutButtons];

 }

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Mostrar botões quando está login:

```
- (void) showLoginButtons{

    NSArray *toolbarButtonsLogin = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: _addButton, _editButton, _flexibleSpace,  _logOutButton, nil];

    //[_myToolbar setItems: toolbarButtonsLogin animated:NO]; // com esta linha também não resulta
    [_myToolbar setItems: toolbarButtonsLogin animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"loginBttons");
}
```

Mostrar os botões disponiveis para utilizadores logout:

```
- (void) showLogoutButtons{

    NSArray *toolbarButtonsLogin = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: _flexibleSpace,  _logInButton, nil];

    //[_myToolbar setItems: toolbarButtonsLogin animated:NO]; // com esta linha também não resulta
    [_myToolbar setItems: toolbarButtonsLogin animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"logoutBttons");
}
```

Logout:

```
- (IBAction)LogOut:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

   User *userObj = [[User alloc] init];
   [userObj logout];

   [self showLogoutButtons];

}
```

LoginViewController:

```
- (IBAction)LogIn:(UIButton *)sender {

    TableViewController *resetButtons = [[TableViewController alloc] init];

    if([userObj userAuthenticated]) {

      [resetButtons showLoginButtons];
      [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
      [self dismissLoginAndShowProfile];

    }

}
```

Já Tentei fazer com: `[_addButton setTintColor: nil];` com `enable/disable`, `removeObj`, e até por a `width: 0.01`, mas nada resulta, apenas comportamentos estranhos sem qualquer razão aparente. O login/logout está a funcionar corretamente sem quaisquer problemas, apenas os botões não fazem o que é suposto (hide/show) consoante o estado do utilizador. Sei também que está a entrar nas funções correctas porque está a imprimir os NSLog correctos.

Comment: sua lógica não estaria ao contrário? Se o usuário está logado, mostrar os botões de logout e vice versa?

Comment: Está correcto. Quando estou logado aparece o botão add, edit e logout e quando não estou aparece apenas o botão para fazer o login.

Answer (score 0):

Não adianta setar a `tintColor` para `nil`.
Se você setar a `tintColor` para `[UIColor clearColor]` e `enabled` para `NO` o botão vai desaparecer.

Comment: Eu utilizaria [button setHidden:YES] ao invés de desabilitar o botão e colocar ele transparente, pois ao meu ver ele continuaria lá, ocupando espaço de algo que poderia ser "clicavel"

Comment: Esse método não existe para um UiBarButtonItem. Existe algum equivalente?

Answer (score -1):

Tente definir o Alpha para `0`, da seguinte forma: `[UIBarButtonItem setAlpha:0];`